# Large Text not being displayed in ScrollViewer for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am having a TextBox inside a ScrollViewer. (windows Phone 8)

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" UseLayoutRounding="True" ManipulationMode="Control" IsHitTestVisible="True">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

When I try to paste large amount of text in the TextBox, some part is visible and some part is truncated, something like this.!

[image]

Using Debugger I can see that the TextBox is getting the full text, it is just not visible.

Any Idea, how to get around this ?

Comment: Is there something in Grid.Row="2" which is taking the space? How are Grid rows defined? Have you tried setting vertical alignment of scrollviewer/TextBox to stretch?

Comment: and what are the grid row definitions?

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViewer height should be smaller than TextBox height, to have smooth scrolling. Hard coding height is not the correct way, but still to understand try setting Height="400" for ScrollViewer and Height="700" for TextBox inside ScrollViewer. Hope it clears the problem.